# NodeJS HTTP Server - How To Verify Client's IP and Login?

Tags: node.js, http-authentication

If I decide to use http module for my server, which module/method(s) I need to do the following?

- To Verify the source IP address of connecting client?
- If the server requires the URL like http://username:password@exmaple.com/method1, how do i setup the Http server of NodeJS to accept such authentication and how do i verify the credentials provided from the client's connection?

Thanks.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

When a client connects to your HTTP server the '`connection`' event is emitted and the argument provided to the callback is a stream of type `net.Socket` which has an attribute called '`remoteAddress`'.  Similarly, each HTTP request passed to your request listener also has a reference to the connection object:

```js
var http = require('http');
var server = http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
  res.end('Hello ' + req.connection.remoteAddress + '!');
  // Client address in request -----^
});
server.on('connection', function(sock) {
  console.log('Client connected from ' + sock.remoteAddress);
  // Client address at time of connection ----^
});
server.listen(9797);
```

As for authentication via embedded credentials in the URL, I don't think this form is reliable as [some web browsers do not pass on the information](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;834489) in the HTTP request (IE and Chrome at least).  You're better off implementing an HTTP standards-based authentication scheme such as [Basic access auth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication) or [Digest access auth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digest_access_authentication).

Answer (score 3):

For HTTP Basic/Digest authentication you can use [http-auth](https://github.com/http-auth/http-auth) module

```
// Authentication module.
var auth = require('http-auth');
var basic = auth.basic({
    realm: "Simon Area.",
    file: __dirname + "/../data/users.htpasswd" // gevorg:gpass, Sarah:testpass ...
});

// Creating new HTTP server.
http.createServer(basic, function(req, res) {
    res.end("Welcome to private area - " + req.user + "!");
}).listen(1337);
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Do not rely on IPs. They are easily spoofed.
2. For basic auth use Connect with http://senchalabs.github.com/connect/middleware-basicAuth.html

Comment: How do you spoof IP ?